# bash integration with terraform

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

i am writing az copy script which captures linux 18.04 system log using azcopy and store it into storage account container, but this whole steps I am doing with terraform automation. i have created machine code and I integrate shell script file with terraform extension.

so the issue is when azcopy copy the file from system and pass to a storage account need azcopy login to authenticate this process but these steps we can't perform through automation.

using following azcopy script and version is v10 please help me on this

```
AzCopy /Source:/var/log/syslog/Dest:https://testingwt.blob.core.windows.net/insights-operational-logs//SourceKey:y/bUACOu/wogikUT1EG0XeaPC4Y6spHcZly2d26QeENKwMiRpjFu5PwmXrThRbNGS3PiPfqEX8WsYC3dg== /S
```

[updated error of azcopy using linux machine in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEoKn.png)

Comment: can you share your tf and bash script?

Comment: @MoonHorse first i am trying this manually but its not work using following script

Comment: AzCopy /Source:/var/log/syslog/Dest:https://testingwt.blob.core.windows.net/insights-operational-logs//SourceKey:y/bUACOu/wogikUT1EG0XeaPC4Y6spHcZly2d26QeENKwMiRpjFu5PwmXrThRbNGS3PiPfqEX8WsYC3dg== /S

Comment: the syntax should be azcopy copy '<local-file-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/<file-name><SAS-token>'. So you should add "azcopy copy" instead of just "azcopy"

Comment: @MoonHorse I believe the SAS token is not a secure method for azcopy so we use access key of the storage account  and my equation is we need to put azcopy login in Linux terminal to interact with portal but I am using automation so how can I define the az copy login and authenticate the code using portal link... is their any option to automate this or any alternative

Comment: you can use azure devops(or a similar CI/CD tool) and keep your secrets there. Inside Azure Devops, you will have a connectors for your Azure account. It will be simpler.

Comment: is there another option which is related to automation or shell script.

Comment: maybe you can clarify your questions by adding more info. Because i didn't understand whether the problem is how to store the secrets or your script doesn't work. By the way, when you are saying script is it just "azcopy copy" command? You say that you are terraforming, please share the tf script by more explanation.

Comment: ya sure @MoonHorse I updated the image of error in the top when I ran the command as per your instruction with access key...note(I am not using Sas token, have added storage account access key)

Answer (score 0):

To upload files to the Storage Blob with a shell script automatically, you can use the SAS token of the storage, or use the `azcopy login` with a service principal or the VM managed identity.

For the SAS token:

```
azcopy copy "/path/to/file" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srt=sco&sp=rwddgcup&se=2019-05-01T05:01:17Z&st=2019-04-30T21:01:17Z&spr=https&sig=MGCXiyEzbtttkr3ewJIh2AR8KrghSy1DGM9ovN734bQF4%3D" --recursive=true
```

For the Service Principal, you need to set the environment variable `AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET` with the secret of the service principal as value and assign the role `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or role `Storage Blob Data Owner` of the storage Blob:

```
azcopy login --service-principal --application-id <application-id> --tenant-id=<tenant-id>
azcopy copy "/path/to/file" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/" --recursive=true
```

For the VM managed identity, you need also to assign the VM managed identity with the role `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or role `Storage Blob Data Owner` of the storage Blob:

```
azcopy login --identity
azcopy copy "/path/to/file" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/" --recursive=true
```

But when you use the VM managed identity, you need to execute the shell script in the Azure VM, it means you need to deploy the Terraform in the Azure VM. So the best way is that use a service principal, you can execute the shell script in other Linux OS, for example, your local Linux machine. The SAS token is also a good way without assigning the role. For more details, see the [Use Azcopy for the Azure Storage Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json).